# How do I change the way my grid container behaves?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive grid container in my website but I'm still working on it. I want  to make it so that when the max-width of the page is 1250px the last box I have inside my grid container [doesn't go to the second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpkXB.jpg) but rather stays on the same row until the page reaches a max-width of 938px where both rows have an equal amount of boxes (2 each).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/noderdowndoop/pen/mdwVKwy)

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>T3 Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <a href="http://t3-ks.com/">
                <div class="logo-container">
                    <img src="/t3s.svg" alt="" class="logo">
                </div>
            </a>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <div class="main-wrapper">
                <div class="title-wrapper">
                    <h1>Menaxhimi i burimeve njerëzore</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="box-btn box-red"></div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="box-btn box-green"></div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="box-btn box-yellow"></div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="box-btn box-blue"></div>
                    </a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

:root {
    --nav-clr:#ebebeb;
    --box-r: #f94144;
    --box-g: #43AA8B;
    --box-y: #F9C74F;
    --box-b: #577590; 
}

body, html {
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

/* nav bar  */

nav {
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: var(--nav-clr);
    align-items: center;
}


.logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 1em;
}


/* buttons  */

.box-btn {
    /* margin: 20px; */
    width: auto;
    height: 259px;
    background: #43AA8B;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.box-btn::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    background: var(--nav-clr);
    z-index: 1;
}

.box-red {
    background-color: var(--box-r);
}

.box-green {
    background-color: var(--box-g);
}

.box-yellow {
    background-color: var(--box-y);
}

.box-blue {
    background-color: var(--box-b);
}

.content {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 230px);
    gap: 20px;

}

/* main  */

.main-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: 80vw;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 5% 65%;
}

/* header  */

.title-wrapper {
    margin: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    grid-row: 1/3;
}

/* SMALLER SCREENS  */

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
    
    .title-wrapper {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: auto;
    }


    nav {
        justify-content: center;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:626px) {
    .content {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 350px);
    }

    .box-btn {
        height: 350px;
    }

    .box-btn::after {
        width: 100%;
        height: 135px;
    }


}

@media screen and (max-width:405px) {
    .title-wrapper {
        font-size: .8em;
    }

    .main-wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you have on the `.container` class `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 230px)` and automatically wraps the containers to fit the screen;

You could:

1. Change it to `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 230px)` to always keep 4 on the same row;
2. Then you can target the 938px with @media screen and change it to `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 230px)`;

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you will have 2 columns with the width of 250px. repeat(2, 250px) = make 2 columns 250px wide each.
If you don't intend to set fixed values for row's sizes, letting them to populate automatically is the way to go.
Consider reading some of these great sources:
[Auto-placement in CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout)
[CSS Grid: row, grid-auto-rows and gap](https://medium.com/geekculture/css-grid-row-b59a2cc3c438)

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 250px);
  grid-row: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  /* background-color: red; */
}

.box-btn {
  margin: 20px;
  width: auto;
  height: 259px;
  background: #43AA8B;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.box-btn::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 210px;
  top: 141px;
  left: -20px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  background: var(--nav-clr);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a href="">
    <div class="box-btn"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="box-btn"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="box-btn"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="box-btn"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```